# few error messages I’m getting inside of unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello all I’m trying to make this match 3 game Similar  Similar To candy crush and I’m writing this code to create my grid in unity and I keep getting stuck with a bunch of errors this is my first time using this website so I’m not sure how to upload things if someone would be so kind to help me I can offer a screen share on my MacBook

Comment: Please post questions according to stack overflow guidelines.

Comment: ie: Show us some code, tell us what is not working and most importantly what you've tried to do, etc.

Comment: Show us the errors and code, you can so it on pictures, take screenshots.